# How to select the radio button randomly(options) using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need solution in selenium webdriver.

Consider I am having 4 radio buttons the id of each radio button will be sequential, for example:

```
Q11_1, Q11_2, Q11_3, Q11_4
```

Each time i have to select different option by randomly.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

try below script in java

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'Q11_')]")) ;
    Random random = new Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(options.size());
    options.get(index).click();
```

I hope, it will works..let me know, if not.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: It's working correctly we need to give our tag name instead of * otherwise it getting the Id which is matched to the whole page

Answer (score 0):

Find all the 4 radio buttons and pick the one randomly using the language which selenium bindings you are using, e.g. in Python you would use [`find_elements_by_xpath()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath) in conjunction with [`starts-with()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with) and [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to pick a random element from a list:

```
import random

options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'Q11_')]") 

option = random.choice(options)
option.click()
```